# What is the difference between an object's scope and its context in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, definition

In the vernacular, **scope** and **context** have a lot in common.  Which is why I get confused when I read references to both, such as in the quote below from an article on closures:

> **Scope** refers to where variables and functions are accessible, and in what **context** it is being executed. ([@robertnyman](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/))

As far as I can tell, context is just a reference to an object.

Can someone please explain what exactly is **context**, as used, for instance, in the jQuery syntax, `$(selector, context)`. And is an object's **scope** the same at it's **context**?

---

> **Update:**
>
> I found this interesting article that talks about both scope and context in JavaScript.
>
> http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Context", as used in this jQuery example, is not a JavaScript term. It is just the name of a variable. It is documented with the rest of the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

Comment: Thanks, though it says:
"However, an alternate **context** can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function."

They still seem to be referring to **context** with that variable.

Comment: Yes. It still isn't a JavaScript term. As it says, by default it searches "starting at the document root" (i.e. the default context is the document root). You can change that.

Answer (score 1):

"context" can mean many things. In the jQuery example you quote it is a reference to a part of the DOM that the selector should be applied to, which has nothing to do with JavaScript contexts.